# ASP.NET MVC WebApi model binding not handling if a property value is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

We were early using **Json.net 6.0.8** and it was properly handling 'undefined' values when posting values to api controller from jquery ajax.

```
For eg, {\"Id\": \"29927801\", \"Status\": 2, \"Name\": undefined}
```

Recently we have upgraded **Json.net to 8.0.3** and looks like it is not properly handling **'undefined'** values - The model itself will be null.
Please share if any suggestions.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share the raw JSON string, without any escaping due to visualizers?  The JSON shown isn't valid, try uploading it to http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should specify Null-value handling for your converters. If we are talking about MVC model binding - you should specify it in app_start. 
Take a look at [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm)

in your WebApiConfig you can write:

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            //... your config

            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
            };

            config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonNetFormatter(settings));
        }
```

Comment: But I was confused how it was working early with 6.0.8 version, even though we have not specified formatter explicitly

Comment: Maybe default nullvalue handling in version 6.0.8 was "Include"